# Implementing a method in a child class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is "better" is Ruby

```
class BaseClass
    def items
      @items ||= get_items
    end

    def get_items
      raise NotImplementedError
    end
end

class ClildClass < BaseClass
  def get_items
    # ... fetching items...
  end
end
```

or simply

```
class BaseClass
    def items
      @items ||= get_items
    end
end

class ClildClass < BaseClass
  def get_items
    # ... fetching items...
  end
end
```

?

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you. There is no right answer for this. You will simply get 2 different errors. First coince should be better if someone else will implement other ChildClasses, because they can see the "interface" they need to implement on their BaseClass.